# mySQL date column is messed up

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

I've made a table:

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date    | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id | int(8)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| isbn    | varchar(13)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price   | decimal(6,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And, the date colomn isn't working. I figured I need to modify the table to default to "CURDATE()". That's what I've got from googling. I'm not even sure if that's the problem, but my alter statement isn't work.

I'm trying to alter with this:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE buybacks MODIFY date date not null default curdate();

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'curdate()' at line 1
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to have column (or table) names that are MySQL reserved words. If you must do this, then use backticks (`) around the name

```
ALTER TABLE buybacks MODIFY `date` date not null default curdate();
```

**EDIT**

However, you can't set a date column to a default of curdate()
See this reference from the [MySQL buglist](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27645) for details

The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP
column. This might be a viable alternative to give you that default

**EDIT 2**

Another alternative would be a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER buybacks_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `buybacks`
   FOR EACH ROW 
       SET NEW.`date` = CURDATE();
```

But watch out that you update a trigger when you do change the name of the date column

Comment: Thanks Mark, after I get it working I'll see about renaming it. That has been a little annoying. It just didn't occur to me when I made the table. Even with the backticks, I'm getting the same error:

`mysql> ALTER TABLE buybacks MODIFY `date` date not null default curdate();
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'curdate()' at line 1`

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I'll try making the datatype TIMESTAMP instead. I really only need YYYY-MM-DD, which is why I was using DATE. I'll convert it over to TIMESTAMP and try only pull that format out when I need the dates.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I ended up changing the datatype to TIMESTAMP and using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. I'm too much of a newbie to get into triggers. 

Thanks a bunch of your help! I'm all fixed up.